# Invoking a common method after a button press

Tags: unity, c#

I want to implement a common method that handles several numeric values and performs and action based on those values. So I have buttons with specific methods to change this values without affecting the rest. However I want to link them all to a final method that runs right after the press of a button, so this way the game will change only when the player chooses to change it and changes according to the players decisions. How can I implement this in my script?
Most of my methods are like this:

```
public void "ButtonIDGoesHere" (int "SpecificVariable"){
//Add, Sub, Multiply, etc. 

}
```

What can I add so that it goes to a common method right after it executes its instructions?

Comment: I might be missing something but can't you just call the shared method from within every click event handler?

Comment: You are right, I didn't saw how simple it was; thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you simply call a common method?

```
public void "ButtonIDGoesHere" (int "SpecificVariable" )
{
    .. whatever you need to do

    // now call the common function
    OnButtonPressed();
}
```

What are we missing?